# Use results from one array in another array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, post

I have a logged in user following other users in a blog. I would like my logged in users to see posts from users they follow.

I run a query that returns a list of user_ids (user_id1) a logged in user (user_id2) follows in an array. I then run the array through a foreach loop to get the list of users as user ids and place it in a new array. The returned user1_ids are echoed as a string. I would now like to use the returned user1_ids in another array that only displays posts based on the user1_ids.

The issue is that the values are returned as a string and my second array used in the posts only reads the first number of the first array as the values are returned as a string and not integers.

How can I use the results from my first array in my second array 'author__in'=> array()? Do I need to convert the string into integers or is there a better method?

```
// The database query that returns the array
<?php
    $currentloggedinuser = get_current_user_id();
    $followers_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_id1 FROM wp_followers WHERE user_id2 = '$currentloggedinuser' ") ?>

// the returned array from the query through foreach placed in another array
<?php
    $following_id = array();
    foreach ($followers_query as $follower) {
    $following_id[] = $follower->user_id1;
    sort($following_id);
    $following_ids = implode(", ",$following_id);
}  
?>

// the resulting number values returned as a string
<?php echo $following_ids;  ?>

                        
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'author__in'=> array($following_ids), // user1_ids I'd like to include from the array above
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );
```

Comment: just do `'author__in'=> $following_id` - that way you are using the array before imploding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably work. I did not test it but it should be fine.

Here is some info on the [$wpdb::get_col method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/)

```
<?php
  $currentloggedinuser = get_current_user_id();

  // Get an array containing only the user_id1 values.

  // It's a good habit to use the prepare method of $wpdb 
  // for security and ease of reading the code

  // Also, you should use $wpdb->prefix instead of using the 'wp_' for the table name
  // that prefix can be changed and your code would break.

  $followers = $wpdb->get_col(
    $wpdb->prepare(
      "SELECT user_id1 FROM {$wpdb->prefix}followers WHERE user_id2 = %d",
      $currentloggedinuser      
    )   
  );

  sort($followers); // or you can just apply sorting in the query above

  // Directly echo the imploded array. 
  // No need to store it in a variable to do so unless you want to use it somewhere else
  echo implode(', ', $followers);

  $args = array(
    'author__in'=> $followers, //use the array we got from the query
    'post_type' => 'post'
  );
```

Comment: thank you so much :) I tried it and it works. Thank you also for the link and prompting me about the prefix and get_col. Sometimes I can't believe how awesome people on stackoverflow are :D Have an amazing day :) haha you made my day :)

Comment: glad I could help :) if the answer helped you, make sure you mark it as the solution :) thanks and have a good day!